# How can I test the validate_uniqueness_of?

Tags: validation, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm hitting a mental block. Can anyone explain to me how I can write a spec test for validate_uniqueness_of?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Or use Shoulda:

```
before do
  @user = Factory(:user)
end

subject { @user }

it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name) }
```

Comment: Or expect syntax, `it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of :name }`

Answer (score 15):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

# spec
describe Foo do
  it "should have a unique name" do
    Foo.create!(:name=>"Foo")
    foo = Foo.new(:name=>"Foo")
    foo.should_not be_valid
    foo.errors[:name].should include("has already been taken")
  end
end
```

Comment: The "include" functionality actually isn't directly provided by RSpec. Instead, when used in this context, RSpec simply looks for a method called "include?" on the object. The String class provides this method. Along the same lines, you could use other String methods such as "should end_with('foobar')", etc.

Answer (score 3):

Make it shorter with Shoulda:

```
it "validates uniqueness of name" do
  FactoryGirl.create(:tag, name: 'unique name')
  should validate_uniqueness_of(:name)
end
```

Comment: … and if you happen to scope it: 
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).scoped_to(:user_group_id) }

Answer (score 2):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end


it "should validate uniqueness of name" do
  user1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  user1.save
  user2 = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
  expect { user2.save! }.to raise_error(
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  )      
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you follow [rubocops ImplicitExpect](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/ImplicitExpect) you might what to use something like this:

```rb
it { is_expected.to validate(%i[name], uniqueness: { scope: :user_group_id }) }
```

or

```rb
it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:name).scoped_to(:user_group_id) }
```