# Ruby on Rails rspec validate uniqueness for a belongs to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rspec, rspec-rails

I created a database where an Artist has many songs. Artist is the name:string. Song is title:string artist:resources. The rspec tests were done with shoulda matchers and I am having trouble validating the uniqueness of a song as I get this error.

```
1) Song Validations is expected to validate that :title is case-sensitively unique
 Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:title) }
 
 Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord::ValidateUniquenessOfMatcher::ExistingRecordInvalid:
   validate_uniqueness_of works by matching a new record against an
   existing record. If there is no existing record, it will create one
   using the record you provide.
 
   While doing this, the following error was raised:
 
     PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "songs" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_5ce8fd4cc7"
     DETAIL:  Key (artist_id)=(1) is not present in table "artists".
 
   The best way to fix this is to provide the matcher with a record where
   any required attributes are filled in with valid values beforehand.
 # ./spec/models/song_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:74:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:73:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ------------------
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # PG::ForeignKeyViolation:
 #   ERROR:  insert or update on table "songs" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_5ce8fd4cc7"
 #   DETAIL:  Key (artist_id)=(1) is not present in table "artists".
 #   <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
```

Here are my models and schema.

app/models/artist.rb

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  has_many :songs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

app/models/song.rb

```
class Song < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
  validates :title, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end
```

Here is the spec that is failing.

app/spec/models/song_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Song, type: :model do
  describe "Associations" do
    it { should belong_to(:artist) }
  end

  describe "Validations" do
    subject { Song.new(title: "Blue man", artist_id: 1 ) }
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:title) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
  end
end
```

Last but not least here is the schema.

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# This file is the source Rails uses to define your schema when running `bin/rails
# db:schema:load`. When creating a new database, `bin/rails db:schema:load` tends to
# be faster and is potentially less error prone than running all of your
# migrations from scratch. Old migrations may fail to apply correctly if those
# migrations use external dependencies or application code.
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_06_18_231822) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "artists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "songs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.bigint "artist_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["artist_id"], name: "index_songs_on_artist_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "songs", "artists"
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

If I remove `subject { Song.new(title: "Blue man", artist_id: 1 )`

There is still an error shown below.

```
Failures:



1) Song Validations is expected to validate that :title is case-sensitively unique
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:title) }
     
Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord::ValidateUniquenessOfMatcher::ExistingRecordInvalid:
       validate_uniqueness_of works by matching a new record against an
       existing record. If there is no existing record, it will create one
       using the record you provide.
         
       While doing this, the following error was raised:
     
         PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "artist_id" of relation "songs" violates not-null constraint
         DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, null, 2022-06-19 14:11:37.525242, 2022-06-19 14:11:37.525242).
     
       The best way to fix this is to provide the matcher with a record where
       any required attributes are filled in with valid values beforehand.
     # ./spec/models/song_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:74:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:73:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # PG::NotNullViolation:
     #   ERROR:  null value in column "artist_id" of relation "songs" violates not-null constraint
     #   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, null, 2022-06-19 14:11:37.525242, 2022-06-19 14:11:37.525242).
     #   <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'

Finished in 0.59196 seconds (files took 5.7 seconds to load)
3 examples, 1 failure
```

Comment: Could you try to remove the `subject { Song.new(title: "Blue man", artist_id: 1 ) }` in the block of `Validation` in the `app/spec/models/song_spec.rb` and see how it goes? As far as I know you don't have to set the subject when using shoulda matcher.

Comment: I get this error when I remove the subject.

Comment: check above to see the error when I remove subject

Comment: I found out the answer you have to change should to expect(song).to validate_uniqueness_of(:title) then it will pass.

Comment: To go along with @George Lugo 's comment, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61225744/7619578